# Get artwork_url from Soundcloud API and show album covers in custom SC/SM2 player

Tags: soundcloud, audio-streaming, soundmanager2

I've been trying to sort out how `artwork_url` can be used from [soundclouds API](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) in order to output *each* cover into [this custom player](https://github.com/kilokeith/soundcloud-soundmanager-player/issues?state=open), and have each appropriate thumb next to its own track in the playlist?

I understand that I need to use the `artwork_url` property, however I do not understand how this is achieved, nor how to integrate it into [this particular custom player plugin](https://github.com/kilokeith/soundcloud-soundmanager-player/issues?state=open). 
Any code examples in particular and/or help is highly appreciated!
*Note: Also would be nice to be able to control the "size" of the artwork as well through other means then just CSS.*

Best

---

**EDIT #1**

I switched the [Soundcloud Custom Player on Heroku](http://soundcloud-sm2.heroku.com/) since after I was able to get it up and running I discovered it to have a much faster load time in contrast to the original player I cited above (even though that one is still quite awesome)...

Im still posed with the same task now however as before - How to add album art to the script and output accordingly?

Pasted below is the [Heroku](http://soundcloud-sm2.heroku.com/docs/application.html) player:

```
// # SoundCloud Custom Player

// Make sure to require [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) before this file on your page.
// And set the defaults for it first:

soundManager.url = 'http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/earpeacerecords/swf';
soundManager.flashVersion = 9;
soundManager.useFlashBlock = false;
soundManager.useHighPerformance = true;
soundManager.wmode = 'transparent';
soundManager.useFastPolling = true;

// Wait for jQuery to load properly

$(function(){

    // Wait for SoundManager2 to load properly

    soundManager.onready(function() {

        // ## SoundCloud
        // Pass a consumer key, which can be created [here](http://soundcloud.com/you/apps), and your playlist url.
        // If your playlist is private, make sure your url includes the secret token you were given.

        var consumer_key = "915908f3466530d0f70ca198eac4288f",
                url = "http://soundcloud.com/poe-epr/sets/eprtistmix1";     

        // Resolve the given url and get the full JSON-worth of data from SoundCloud regarding the playlist and the tracks within.

        $.getJSON('http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=' + url + '&format=json&consumer_key=' + consumer_key + '&callback=?', function(playlist){

            // I like to fill out the player by passing some of the data from the first track.
            // In this case, you'll just want to pass the first track's title.

            $('.title').text(playlist.tracks[0].title);

            // Loop through each of the tracks

            $.each(playlist.tracks, function(index, track) {

                // Create a list item for each track and associate the track *data* with it.

                $('<li>' + track.title + '</li>').data('track', track).appendTo('.tracks');

                // * Get appropriate stream url depending on whether the playlist is private or public.
                // * If the track includes a *secret_token* add a '&' to the url, else add a '?'.
                // * Finally, append the consumer key and you'll have a working stream url.

                url = track.stream_url;

                (url.indexOf("secret_token") == -1) ? url = url + '?' : url = url + '&';

                url = url + 'consumer_key=' + consumer_key;

                // ## SoundManager2
                // **Create the sound using SoundManager2**

                soundManager.createSound({

                    // Give the sound an id and the SoundCloud stream url we created above.

                    id: 'track_' + track.id,
                    url: url,

                    // On play & resume add a *playing* class to the main player div.
                    // This will be used in the stylesheet to hide/show the play/pause buttons depending on state.

                    onplay: function() {

                        $('.player').addClass('playing');

                        $('.title').text(track.title);

                    },
                    onresume: function() {

                        $('.player').addClass('playing');

                    },

                    // On pause, remove the *playing* class from the main player div.

                    onpause: function() {
                        $('.player').removeClass('playing');
                    },

                    // When a track finished, call the Next Track function. (Declared at the bottom of this file).

                    onfinish: function() {
                        nextTrack();
                    }

                });

            });

        });

        // ## GUI Actions

        // Bind a click event to each list item we created above.

        $('.tracks li').live('click', function(){

            // Create a track variable, grab the data from it, and find out if it's already playing *(set to active)*

            var $track = $(this),
                    data = $track.data('track'),
                    playing = $track.is('.active');

            if (playing) {

                // If it is playing: pause it.

                soundManager.pause('track_' + data.id);             

            } else {

                // If it's not playing: stop all other sounds that might be playing and play the clicked sound.

                if ($track.siblings('li').hasClass('active')) { soundManager.stopAll(); }

                soundManager.play('track_' + data.id);

            }

            // Finally, toggle the *active* state of the clicked li and remove *active* from and other tracks.

            $track.toggleClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');

        });

        // Bind a click event to the play / pause button.

        $('.play, .pause').live('click', function(){

            if ( $('li').hasClass('active') == true ) {

                // If a track is active, play or pause it depending on current state.

                soundManager.togglePause( 'track_' + $('li.active').data('track').id ); 

            } else {

                // If no tracks are active, just play the first one.

                $('li:first').click();

            }

        });

        // Bind a click event to the next button, calling the Next Track function.

        $('.next').live('click', function(){
            nextTrack();
        });

        // Bind a click event to the previous button, calling the Previous Track function.

        $('.prev').live('click', function(){
            prevTrack();
        });

        // ## Player Functions

        // **Next Track**

        var nextTrack = function(){

            // Stop all sounds

            soundManager.stopAll();

            // Click the next list item after the current active one. 
            // If it does not exist *(there is no next track)*, click the first list item.

            if ( $('li.active').next().click().length == 0 ) {
                $('.tracks li:first').click();
            }

        }

        // **Previous Track**

        var prevTrack = function(){

            // Stop all sounds

            soundManager.stopAll();

            // Click the previous list item after the current active one. 
            // If it does not exist *(there is no previous track)*, click the last list item.

            if ( $('li.active').prev().click().length == 0 ) {
                $('.tracks li:last').click();
            }

        }

    });

});
```

---

**EDIT #2**

So I strangely was able to work something out... I have no clue if its semantically correct however...

```
$.getJSON('http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=' + url + '&format=json&consumer_key=' + consumer_key + '&callback=?', function(playlist){

            // I like to fill out the player by passing some of the data from the first track.
            // In this case, you'll just want to pass the first track's title.

            $('.title').text(playlist.tracks[0].title);
            $('.album_art').attr('src', playlist.artwork_url);

            // Loop through each of the tracks

            $.each(playlist.tracks, function(index, track) {

                // Create a list item for each track and associate the track *data* with it.

                $('<li>' + '<img src="' + playlist.artwork_url + '">' + track.title + '</li>').data('track', track).appendTo('.tracks');

                // * Get appropriate stream url depending on whether the playlist is private or public.
                // * If the track includes a *secret_token* add a '&' to the url, else add a '?'.
                // * Finally, append the consumer key and you'll have a working stream url.

                url = track.stream_url;

                (url.indexOf("secret_token") == -1) ? url = url + '?' : url = url + '&';

                url = url + 'consumer_key=' + consumer_key;

                // ## SoundManager2
                // **Create the sound using SoundManager2**

                soundManager.createSound({

                    // Give the sound an id and the SoundCloud stream url we created above.

                    id: 'track_' + track.id,
                    url: url,

                    // On play & resume add a *playing* class to the main player div.
                    // This will be used in the stylesheet to hide/show the play/pause buttons depending on state.

                    onplay: function() {

                        $('.player').addClass('playing');

                        $('.title').text(track.title);

                    },
                    onresume: function() {

                        $('.player').addClass('playing');

                    },

                    // On pause, remove the *playing* class from the main player div.

                    onpause: function() {
                        $('.player').removeClass('playing');
                    },

                    // When a track finished, call the Next Track function. (Declared at the bottom of this file).

                    onfinish: function() {
                        nextTrack();
                    }

                });

            });
```

---

**EDIT #3**

Below is the HTML and CSS markup that works with the player for better clarification...

**HTML**

```
            <div class='title'></div>
            <a class='prev'>Previous</a>
            <a class='play'>Play</a>
            <a class='pause'>Pause</a>
            <a class='next'>Next</a>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Soundcloud Player
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

#sticky_header #sticky_content .player {
    height: 570px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#sticky_header #sticky_content .tracks {

}

#sticky_header #sticky_content .tracks li {
    cursor: pointer;    
    height: 40px;
    text-align: left;
}

#sticky_header #sticky_content .tracks li img.album_art {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 15px; 
}

#sticky_header #sticky_content .title {

}

#sticky_header #sticky_content .prev {

}

#sticky_header #sticky_content .play {
    display: block; 
}

#sticky_header #sticky_content .playing .play {
    display: none; 
}

#sticky_header #sticky_content .pause {
    display: none; 
}

#sticky_header #sticky_content .playing .pause {
    display: block; 
}

#sticky_header #sticky_content .next {}
```

Comment: Sorry, no. I'm admittedly much greener at JQuery than I am PHP. Im able to piece together snippets of code and understand very basic functions at the moment so the scope of adding this in is a bit over my head thus why Im here.

Comment: can you please copy your code to something like http://jsbin.com ?

Comment: Whoops, sure... once sec.

Comment: I apologize for the delay. A family emergency occurred. I will report back soon. Thank you for your help Misha.

Answer (score 2):

to get an image you can use this code:

```
//get element by id from your iframe
var widget = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('soundcloud_widget'));
widget.getCurrentSound(function(music){
    artwork_url = music.artwork_url.replace('-large', '-t200x200');
    $('#song1').css('background', 'url(\"'+artwork_url+'\") ');
});
```

normaly you get a link with "-large" at the end and the size is 100x100. If you want other sizes you have to change the end with ".replace" like I did. A list with available sizes can you find here:

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks
(my size 200x200 is not listed but works. Maybe there are more sizes like every hundred px.)

at the moment the code works only for the actual playing song. For me it's not a solution, because i need all images from my playlist.

Answer (score 1):

Here's where iterating over the tracks retrieved from the API happeninng:

```
// Loop through each of the tracks
$.each(playlist.tracks, function(index, track) {
  // Create a list item for each track and associate the track *data* with it.
  $('<li>' + track.title + '</li>').data('track', track).appendTo('.tracks');
```

Inside of the iterator function you can now access `track.artwork_url` and possibly set it as a background image or perhaps background for some element, maybe something like:

```
$('<li><img src=" + track.artwork_url + "></img>' + track.title + '</li>').data('track', track).appendTo('.tracks');
```

I hope this helps.

**UPD**. In your updated code, you should refer to `track.artwork_url` instead of `playlist` – then you'll get each track's individual artwork.

Comment: Ahh cool!. So apparently I didnt even need `$('.album_art').attr('src', playlist.artwork_url);` before the iterator function. So how could this be done in reverse - eg. instead of having each tracks artwork show up alongside each track in the playlist, how could I just show the currently playing tracks artwork? --- Also, how do I access different artwork sizes?